# Debugging Random JavaScript Errors in CRM 2015 Turbo Forms

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm receiving random errors in multiple forms/entities for my CRM 2015.1 Online instance.  I recently reset my site map, hoping that would help, and it hasn't.  What is causing these errors, and how do I fix it?

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null</Message>
   <Line>0</Line>
   <URL>/form/page.aspx?lcid=1033&themeId=b03aadd8-2a2a-406f-4365-9d9e69561feb&tstamp=70515986&updateTimeStamp=635742898971441709&userts=130912363895311265&ver=-682775896#etc=112&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d112%26etc%3d112%26id%3d%257bE3257540-4327-E511-80F8-FC15B428DC1C%257d%26rskey%3d%257b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001028%257d&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&rskey=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001028%7d&counter=1446763863308</URL>
   <PageURL>/form/page.aspx?lcid=1033&themeId=b03aadd8-2a2a-406f-4365-9d9e69561feb&tstamp=70515986&updateTimeStamp=635742898971441709&userts=130912363895311265&ver=-682775896#etc=112&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d112%26etc%3d112%26id%3d%257bE3257540-4327-E511-80F8-FC15B428DC1C%257d%26rskey%3d%257b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001028%257d&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&rskey=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001028%7d&counter=1446763863308</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(){var$v_0=this.$8q_1.toDictionary();var$$dict_3=$v_0;for(var$$key_4in$$dict_3){var$v_2={key:$$key_4,value:$$dict_3[$$key_4]};var$v_3=$v_2.value;if(!$v_3.$5Y_2){$v_3.initialize();}}var$v_1=this.get_viewMap().toDictionary();var$$dict_9=$v_1;for(va</Function>
   <FunctionRaw>function () {
        var $v_0 = this.$8q_1.toDictionary();
        var $$dict_3 = $v_0;
        for (var $$key_4 in $$dict_3) {
            var $v_2 = { key: $$key_4, value: $$dict_3[$$key_4] };
            var $v_3 = $v_2.value;
            if (!$</FunctionRaw>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(){var$v_0=this.$8q_1.toDictionary();var$$dict_3=$v_0;for(var$$key_4in$$dict_3){var$v_2={key:$$key_4,value:$$dict_3[$$key_4]};var$v_3=$v_2.value;if(!$v_3.$5Y_2){$v_3.initialize();}}var$v_1=this.get_viewMap().toDictionary();var$$dict_9=$v_1;for(var$$key_Ain$$dict_9){var$v_4={key:$$key_A,value:$$dict_9[$$key_A]};var$v_5=$v_4.value;try{$v_5.bind();}catch($v_6){Mscrm.CrmDebug.fail(String.format('Exceptionencounteredbinding{0}:{1}',$v_5.getKey(),$v_6.message));catchError($v_6.message,window.location.href,0,true);}}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){this.$9B_1=true;this.ui.bindUI();if(this.$4B_1.toArray().length>0){Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().startUIUpdate();}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){this.$N_1.bindUI();}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2){var$v_0=$p0._error;if(!IsNull($v_0)){var$v_1=Mscrm.ErrorInformation.createErrorInfo($v_0.Code,$v_0.DisplayText,$v_0.SerializedException);var$v_2=Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject('errorDialogCallback',Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper,null,false);openErrorDlg($v_0.Code,$v_0.DisplayText,$v_1,0,0,$v_2);return;}else{for(var$$arr_6=$p0.Descriptor.FormDescriptor,$$len_7=$$arr_6.length,$$idx_8=0;$$idx_8<$$len_7;++$$idx_8){var$v_C=$$arr_6[$$idx_8];Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Fo($v_C);}var$v_3='TODO:Handlelayouttemplatenotfound.';var$v_4=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3n();$v_4.descriptors=$p0.Descriptor.FormDescriptor;$v_4.ProcessControlRule=$p0.processControlRule;$v_4.primaryFormId=newMicrosoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.Guid($p0.Descriptor.PrimaryFormId);$v_4.entityMetadata=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Gl($p0.entityMetadata);$v_4.InlineEditSubGrids=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Gm($p0.InlineEditSubGrids);var$v_5=$p0.header;$v_4.applicationInitDeferredStatements=$p0.header.ApplicationInitDeferredStatements;$v_4.sfaTabsInitDeferredStatements=$p0.header.SFATabsInitDeferredStatements;$v_4.caseSFATabsInitDeferredStatements=$p0.header.CaseSFATabsInitDeferredStatements;var$v_6=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('InjectLayoutIncludestoPage');$v_6.start();Sys.Application.beginCreateComponents();eval($v_5.TurboApplicationInitStatements);Sys.Application.endCreateComponents();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$FS($v_5.StyleIncludes);Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$F4($v_5.TurboScriptIncludes);Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.DisposalManager.clearExistingDataClientVariables();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.DisposalManager.clearExistingLayoutClientVariables();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$FR($v_5.ClientVariables);$v_6.stop();var$v_7=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('RenderFormLayout');$v_7.start();var$v_8=$v_5.JQueryTemplates;$v_4.templates=$v_8;for(var$v_D=0;$v_D<$v_8.length;$v_D++){var$v_E=$v_8[$v_D];if($v_E.Key==='rootJQueryTemplate'){$v_3=$v_E.Value;break;}}Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$H1($v_3);$v_7.stop();var$v_9=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('InitializeApplicationComponents');$v_9.start();Sys.Application.beginCreateComponents();eval(createFormControlLite);eval(createPageManager);eval(createEventManager);eval(SubGridCommandBarData);Sys.Application.endCreateComponents();$v_9.stop();if($v_4.formType!==7&&!$v_4.recordId.equals(Microsoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.Guid.get_empty())){var$v_F=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('RequestSubgridsData');$v_F.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$H3();$v_F.stop();}var$v_A=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('InitializeXrmControlsandData');$v_A.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().initialize();$v_A.stop();var$v_B=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('BindXrmtoHTML');$v_B.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().bindUI();$v_B.stop();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().initializeProcessControl($v_4);$v_4.layoutReady=true;Xrm.XrmPerformance.measureTime('OnLayoutReadyhandlers',function(){returnMscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$8D('OnLayoutReady');});Mscrm.Performance.PerformanceMarkerManager.get_instance().addMarker('PageReadyforDataBind',1);Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$DR($p1,$p2);}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p1_0){$v_0.stop();var$v_1=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('ParseFormLayoutResponseJson');$v_1.start();var$v_2=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$CS($p1_0);$v_1.stop();if($v_2){var$v_3=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$EL($p1);var$v_4=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$EK($p1);var$v_5=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('ProcessFormLayout');$v_5.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Go($v_2,$v_3,$v_4);$v_5.stop();}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){if($v_0.readyState!==4){return;}$v_0.onreadystatechange=null;if($v_0.status!==200){}successCallback($v_0.responseText);$v_0=null;}</Function>
    <Function>requestPage(requestUrl,successCallback,asynchronous,headers)</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1){var$v_0=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('RequestFormLayout');$v_0.start();setLoadingText(Xrm.Internal.getResourceString('LOCID_PAGE_LOADING_REQUEST_DATA'));requestPage($p0,function($p1_0){$v_0.stop();var$v_1=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('ParseFormLayoutResponseJson');$v_1.start();var$v_2=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$CS($p1_0);$v_1.stop();if($v_2){var$v_3=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$EL($p1);var$v_4=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$EK($p1);var$v_5=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('ProcessFormLayout');$v_5.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Go($v_2,$v_3,$v_4);$v_5.stop();}},false,$p1);}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1){Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$EA();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().$B_1=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.layoutReady=false;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.DisposalManager.setLastFormLoadTimeoutIntervalJobId();var$v_0=[];Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$53($v_0,'x-crm-mismatch',$p0);Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Cc($p1.toString(),$v_0);}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1){var$v_0=null;if(IsNull($p1)||!$p1||IsNull(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formDataResponseAfterParse)){var$v_1=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Et();if(IsNullOrEmptyString($v_1)){setLoadingText(Xrm.Internal.getResourceString('LOCID_PAGE_LOADING_REQUEST_DATA'));window.setTimeout(function(){returnMscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$DR($p0);},15);return;}$v_0=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$CS($v_1);var$v_2=$v_0._error;if(!IsNull($v_2)){var$v_3=Mscrm.ErrorInformation.createErrorInfo($v_2.Code,$v_2.DisplayText,$v_2.SerializedException);var$v_4=Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject('errorDialogCallback',Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper,null,false);openErrorDlg($v_2.Code,$v_2.DisplayText,$v_3,0,0,$v_4);return;}else{Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formDataResponseAfterParse=$v_0;}}else{$v_0=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formDataResponseAfterParse;}setLoadingText(Xrm.Internal.getResourceString('LOCID_PAGE_LOADING_PROCESSING_DATA'));$v_0.formData._formId=newMicrosoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.Guid($v_0.formData._formId.toString());Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData=$v_0.formData;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.commandBarData=$v_0.commandBarData;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.wrpcTokenData=$v_0.tokenData;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.businessRulesVersion=$v_0.businessRulesVersion;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.FormVersion=$v_0.formVersion;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.attributeMappingXml=$v_0.mappedXmlString;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.entityDisplayName=$v_0.entityDisplayName;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.isCustomImagePresentInDatabase=$v_0.isCustomImagePresentInDatabase;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$8Q=false;if(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData&&Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.layoutReady){Mscrm.Performance.PerformanceMarkerManager.get_instance().addMarker('DataReady',1);var$v_5=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('BindDataandCreateControls');$v_5.start();var$v_6=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('ProcessCachedLayout');$v_6.start();var$v_7=Mscrm.TurboForm.Common.LayoutUrlCache.get_instance().getUrl(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.etc,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.navigationFormId,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.processId,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formType);var$v_8=Mscrm.CrmUri.create(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData._formlayoutUrl);var$v_9=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.navigationFormId.equals(Microsoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.Guid.get_empty());var$v_A=!$v_7;var$v_B=!Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.navigationFormId.equals(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData._formId);if($v_B){Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.navigationFormId=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData._formId;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.primaryFormId=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData._formId;}Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$Hs();var$v_C=!Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.ProcessControlBootstrapper.bindProcessId(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3);Mscrm.TurboForm.Common.LayoutUrlCache.get_instance().addUrl(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.etc,Microsoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.Guid.get_empty(),Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.processId,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formType,$v_8);Mscrm.TurboForm.Common.LayoutUrlCache.get_instance().addUrl(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.etc,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.navigationFormId,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.processId,Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formType,$v_8);if($v_A&&($v_9||!$v_B)&&!$v_C){var$v_J=[];Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$53($v_J,'x-crm-duplicate',$p0);requestPage($v_8.toString(),function(){},true,$v_J);}else{var$v_K=$v_A||$v_7.toString()!==$v_8.toString();if($v_K){Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$H7($p0,$v_8);return;}}$v_6.stop();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.DisposalManager.clearExistingDataClientVariables();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$FQ($v_0.clientVariables);Sys.Application.initialize();var$v_D=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('LoadPBLWebresource');$v_D.start();var$v_E=Mscrm.CrmUri.create('/_forms/formscript.js.aspx');$v_E.get_query()['formname']='crmform';$v_E.get_query()['airenabled']=true;$v_E.get_query()['businessrulesversion']=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.businessRulesVersion;$v_E.get_query()['formid']=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.navigationFormId;$v_E.get_query()['fver']=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.FormVersion;Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.CustomScriptsManager.get_instance().loadWebResource($v_E);Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.CustomScriptsManager.get_instance().executeHandler('Mscrm.BusinessRulesScript.Initialize','',null);$v_D.stop();var$v_F=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('CreateCommonControls');$v_F.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$E1();$v_F.stop();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().bindData(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3);Xrm.XrmPerformance.measureTime('OnDataBoundhandler',function(){returnMscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$8D('OnDataBound');});var$v_G=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('CreateQuickForm');$v_G.start();if(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formType===7){Mscrm.GlobalQuickCreate.GlobalQuickCreateBehavior.showGlobalQuickCreate();Mscrm.GlobalQuickCreate.GlobalQuickCreateBehavior.showGlobalQuickCreateContainer(window.frameElement.id,true);}$v_G.stop();var$v_H=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('CreateRecordSetControl');$v_H.start();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$E6();$v_H.stop();var$v_I=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('AddItemtoMRU');$v_I.start();Mscrm.Utilities.addEntityToRecent(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.formData._entity);$v_I.stop();Mscrm.Utilities.showHideHierarchyButton(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$3.get_isFormHierarchyEnabled());$v_5.stop();}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){returnMscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.$DR($p0);}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>undefined</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>undefined</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>undefined</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1920x1080</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClienState>Online</ClienState>
   <ClientTime>2015-11-05T17:51:08</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{8925BAEE-9186-419B-A1B4-422FE0539E27}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{31CBF85A-DF03-E511-80F5-FC15B428AD68}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>7.1.1.3157</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Comment: You seem to be referencing an XML that isn't loaded yet. Turboforms might do that since all is loaded in parallell. You will have to make a loop to see if the XML is loaded, otherwise wait X s, which of course will make the loading slower.

Comment: I don't believe I'm loading any XML.  Could it be a CRM Turbo forms bug?

Comment: It could be, but I haven't heard any general bugs. 
It's this line: <Message>Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null</Message> that made me think that there was some sort of XML that made the issue. Do you have ANY scripts onload of the form? If yes, does it work when you turn them off?

Comment: This is happening on multiple entities @RickardN  Not sure what it would be...

Comment: Can you check if there are any js enabled on the forms that give these errors?